# Semrush says sitemap.xml contains an incorrect page due to non-canonical URL

Tags: seo, php, canonical-url, xml-sitemap, semrush

I am having an issue with my home page or `index.php` page. When I set canonical to

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

I get an SEO error from Semrush for `https://example.com/home` saying "incorrect page found in sitemap.xml - Non-canonical URL"

If I set canonical to

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/home" />
```

I get the SEO error for `https://example.com/`

With PHP I have tried the following:

```
<?php $currentPage = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/<?php echo $currentPage; ?>" />
```

But this gives me a bunch of SEO errors saying I have duplicate title tags, duplicate content and duplicate meta description for (`https://example.com/`, `https://example.com`, `https://example.com/home`)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @user979331 What is your CMS? Wordpress? Drupal? The accepted answer addresses the canonical part of your problem. There are still issues that need to be dealt with properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two URLs pointing to **the same content**, you need to mark one of them as canonical.

So if `/` and `/home` give you the same page, then **both** pages should say:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
```

Just to be clear: **both** should say that. **Neither** should say:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/home"><!-- this is wrong -->
```

**In addition** only the canonical page should appear in sitemap.xml. `/home` should **not** appear in sitemap.xml. (It doesn't make sense to say "Please index `/home`" in the sitemap only to immediately say "Don't index `/home`, index `/` instead" in the page itself)

Comment: In addition, you should never link to `/home` or `/index.php` on the site, you should always link to `/`.